# show a fadeIn effect in this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that will show a LOADING image when page is loading:

```
<script>
function onReady(callback) {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);

    function checkReady() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            callback.call(this);
        }
    }
}

function show(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}

onReady(function () {
    show('all', true);
    show('loading', false);
});
</script>
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ag4dte6u/)

What I want to do is add a fadeIn effect to show div #all WHEN LOADING is complete.

Can I add a fadeIn effect in `function show`? Can I use jquery? Any ideas?

Comment: If you're considering using jquery, why not spend fifteen minutes browsing through [the complete list of jquery methods](http://api.jquery.com)? You'll quickly see a method called `fadeIn()`...

Comment: I thought I could not use jquery with javascript... that is why I asked. thank you friend! @nnnnnn

Comment: Jquery is a collection of functions written in javascript to save you having to write them yourself, it's not another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following to function for fade in & fade out effect using javascript. [CREDIT](http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/)

```
    function fadeIn(el, display) {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    el.style.display = display || "block";

    (function fade() {
        var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
        if (!((val += .01) > 1)) {
            el.style.opacity = val;
            requestAnimationFrame(fade);
        }
    })();
}

function fadeOut(el) {
    el.style.opacity = 1;

    (function fade() {
        if ((el.style.opacity -= .01) < 0) {
            el.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            requestAnimationFrame(fade);
        }
    })();
}
```

And change your show function to following.

```
function show(id, value) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if(value)
        fadeIn(el)
    else 
        fadeOut(el);
}
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ag4dte6u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `fadeIn` method. e.g

```
function show(id, value) {
    if(value){
        $("#" + id).fadeIn(2000);
    } else{
        $('#' +id).hide();
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/az9uaspr/

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your "head" tag:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And Just change your show() like this:-

```
  function show(id, value) {

if(value)
  $("#"+id).fadeIn("2000");
else
  $("#"+id).hide();
 }
```